# SQL Update отказывается работать если не находит в одной из таблиц условие

Tags: sql, mysqli

Доброго времени суток ) Вот , собственно сам запрос..

```
UPDATE cstm_exhib, cstm_person, cstm_history
    SET cstm_exhib.id_cstm = '319',
        cstm_person.id_cstm = '319',
        cstm_history.id_cstm = '319'
    WHERE cstm_exhib.id_cstm = '10' AND cstm_exhib.id_exhib NOT IN ('22', '5')
    AND cstm_person.id_cstm = '10'
    AND cstm_history.id_cstm = '10'
```

если в какой либо таблице не находит id_cstm = '10' прекращает работу и выдает - Затронуто 0 строк. Подскажите плиз в чем дело? )

Comment: Дело в том, что используется INNER JOIN, причём его устаревший comma style синтаксис. Если в одной из таблиц нет соответствующей записи, то весь выходной набор пуст. Поскольку условий связывания я лично не вижу, то самый правильный подход - три отдельных запроса. Возможно, одним пакетом. *прекращает работу* Не прекращает. Работу, в том виде как она сформулирована, запрос выполнил. Ну а то, что ты попросил не то, что хотел - так это не сервера косяк.